# Firebase child node refuse to be deleted

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

i had a problem with my application where sometimes it successfully delete a file and most of the time it is failed to delete it. At first i thought it was my application that had the problem. here is how it looked in my application, the button that i clicked is the delete button :

[image: App Click]

But, then i tried to delete the data directly from firebase realtime database but the child node is refused to be deleted. here is how it looked :

[image: Firebase Click]

I tried to check my delete function. But, i dont think there is anything wrong with it. here is my delete function :

```
    private fun removeData(id : String){
        val dataRef = ref.child(preferences.getValue("username").toString()).child("FoodList").child(id)
        val Image = StorageRef.child(preferences.getValue("username").toString()).child("food_pics").child(id)
        dataRef.removeValue()
        Image.delete()
    }
```

I tried to look for this problem everywhere but i still got no answer. I hope anyone in here could help me, thanks

Comment: From the animation it seems as if the data *is* being deleted, but is then immediately written back. Nothing in Firebase itself does such an action, so you likely have a process somewhere doing it. I recommend checking for any process you might still have running that writes data based on what it read before.

Comment: Does using ValueEventListener could create such behavior to the realtime database? because that usually happen after i update a child data value and then tried to delete the child node

Comment: I see from the answer you posted that you found the problem already. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turnout this problem is caused by a ValueEventListener in my program which is used to set a value to my realtime database.This create a value to be set continuously by my program. Which then, create such behavior in the realtime database. Before, it was like this :

```
        dataRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                Log.w("PicUrl data",PicUrl)
                dataRef.child("name").setValue(food_name)
                dataRef.child("avail").setValue(availability)
                dataRef.child("price").setValue(food_price.toInt())
                dataRef.child("id").setValue(id)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }
        })
```

now i just simply set the value without ValueEventListener :

```
        dataRef.child("name").setValue(food_name)
        dataRef.child("avail").setValue(availability)
        dataRef.child("price").setValue(food_price.toInt())
        dataRef.child("id").setValue(id)
```